# R Ggplot2 Dot Plot - is it possible to reorder the axis categories/values based on the frequency of a different variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am visualizing longitudinal data for each patient, plotting each patient's event over time on a dot plot. I am trying to figure out a way to make this plot more readable. I am thinking to group/cluster patients who have a specific event into a specific location on the dot plot (i.e. patients with event=1 will be clustered towards the top) .

This is the ggplot R code I have so far:

```
patient_plot <- ggplotly(
  ggplot(cohort, aes(x = event_date, y = patient_id_factor, group = event, color = event)) +
    geom_point(size = 1) + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=5)))
```

which produces this plot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEk3G.png). I am trying to cluster the pink patients with event=1 towards the top of the plot, and am wondering if that is possible. I would also be open to any other different tips or suggestions you all may have to make this plot more readable.

Thank you in advance for any tips or help!

Answer (score 1):

`forcats::fct_infreq` can do this for you:

Reproducible example of your plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(42)
cohort <- data.frame(
  event_date = as.Date("2021-01-01") + rpois(80, 200),
  event = sample(5, 80, replace = TRUE, prob = 5:1),
  patient_id_factor = as.character(sample(10, 80, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:10)))

ggplot(cohort, aes(x = event_date, y = patient_id_factor, group = event, color = event)) +
    geom_point(size = 1) + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=5))
```

Using `forcats::fct_infreq` to reorder the patient id as a factor in order of frequency, with infrequent near the top:

```
library(forcats)
cohort %>%
  mutate(patient_id_factor = fct_infreq(patient_id_factor)) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = event_date, y = patient_id_factor, group = event, color = event)) +
  geom_point(size = 1) + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help Jon! The fct_infreq option was veryhelpful :)